# Get nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have a datarow in excel as

> 'Ars','Cr','Assl','Burg','Consp'

I want to convert it into nested dictionary like this

```
 data_dict.update({'name':'Ars','children':[{
                  'name':'Cr','children':[{
                  'name':'Assl','children':[{
                  'name':'Burg','children':[{
                  'name':'Consp','children':[{
                  'none'}]}]}]}]}]}
```

I am trying to write a recursive method to update my dictionary

```
def update(row,idx,data_dict):
   if idx==len(row):
     return data_dict
  else:
     data_dict.update({'name':row[idx],'children':update(row,idx+1,{})}
```

I am pretty sure the last line is wrong but I cant figure out a way to create this structure

P.S updated the question to include square brackets
Thanks

Comment: `'children':{'none'}` is not a dictionary

Comment: Assuming you have many rows like that and want to build a kind of tree structure. Wouldn't a structure like `{'Ars': {'Cr': {'Assl': {'Burg': {'Consp': None}}}}}` be more to the point? Otherwise you keep overriding the `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

keys = ['Ars', 'Cr', 'Assl', 'Burg', 'Consp']

result = reduce(lambda x, y: {"name": y, "children": x}, reversed(keys), None)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'name': 'Ars', 'children': {'name': 'Cr', 'children': {'name': 'Assl', 'children': {'name': 'Burg', 'children': {'name': 'Consp', 'children': None}}}}}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need brackets do the following:

```
from functools import reduce

keys = ['Ars', 'Cr', 'Assl', 'Burg', 'Consp']

result = reduce(lambda x, y: {"name": y, "children": [x]}, reversed(keys), None)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'name': 'Ars', 'children': [{'name': 'Cr', 'children': [{'name': 'Assl', 'children': [{'name': 'Burg', 'children': [{'name': 'Consp', 'children': [None]}]}]}]}]}
```

Basically just add brackets around `x` in the lambda function.

Comment: `reduce` is slicker than mine - nice

Comment: Hi Daniel Thanks for the answer however I made one mistake i need to wrap children in '[]' square brackets. Can you please also help me with that

Comment: Hi Rohit, could you add an example, to make it clear?

Comment: @Rohit Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['Ars','Cr','Assl','Burg','Consp']

d_ = d = {}

for name, val in zip(l, l[1:]):
    d['name'] = val
    d['children'] = d = {}

d_
```

evaluates to

```
{'name': 'Cr',
 'children': {'name': 'Assl',
  'children': {'name': 'Burg', 'children': {'name': 'Consp', 'children': {}}}}}
```